# Draggable popup positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using Oracle Applications Framework (OAF) and incoporated a jquery popup with it. What happens is OAF auto generates the popup div like so:

```
<DIV role=dialog tabIndex=-1 aria-describedby=remainingTrancheTipRN class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front center-dialog ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="HEIGHT: auto; WIDTH: 300px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 0px; DISPLAY: block; TOP: 0px" aria-labelledby=ui-id-1 jQuery1111025367763936550064="14">
```

I need the popup to be draggable and on the center after clicking it. The problem is, the div auto generates an inline css with LEFT and TOP positions as 0px meaning it is not centered. I tried to center it using !important in css BUT by doing so it now won't be draggable since the left and top positions are now fixed at center via !important. Is there a way to delete the inline css of the div? I tried the ff but to no avail:

```
  $(this).css('display', '');
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
```

UPDATE:

Weird, as it is working well with chrome. Not working on IE11. When I inspected the page, the div in chrome looks like this:

```
  <div id="remainingTrancheTipRN" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content"   style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 77px; max-height: none; height: auto;">
```

Any ideas why they differ?

Comment: Have you tried $(this).attr( "style", "" ); ?

Comment: I have. I'm thinking this has got more to do with OAF but I don't know how